# perl YAML::Tiny Searching for a second level value in a hash of hash

Tags: perl, hash, yaml

I have a hash of hash value in a YAML::Tiny object, as

```
        $yaml = YAML::Tiny->read_string($config);
```

Now, I am trying to check for a specific value inside this hash of hash, and if the value matches, take it's key, by

```
        foreach my $key (keys %{$yaml->[0]}){
               if ( values %{$yaml->[0]->{$key}} =~ /My_String/){
                   print $key;
               }
```

But it is giving

```
Applying pattern match (m//) to %hash will act on scalar(%hash) at script.pl line 25.
Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref at script.pl line 25.
```

I guess it is because values %{$yaml->[0]->{$key} is also returning a hash, because the object itself is a hash of hash. What am I doing wrong here?

Test data::

```
'string_1' => {
                      'test_data' => 82,
                      'test_data1' => 99,
                      'test_data2' => My_string
                    },
'string_2' => {
                     'test_data3' => 97,
                     'test_data4' => 67
                   }
    };
```

and I am looking for printing test_data2 because it's value is My_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. Precedence: Perl understands the expression as `values( %{...} =~ /.../ )`:

   ```
   $ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e 'values %{ {a=>3} } =~ /x/'
   values((%{+{'a', 3};} =~ /x/));
   ```
2. Even after fixing it: Binding operator can be used on a scalar (string). `values` returns a list. What exactly are you trying to do?

**Update:** The following scripts does what you want while still trying to keep the logic you had in mind, i.e. it replaces the inner for-loop with a grep.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $yaml = [{
            'string_1' => {
                           'test_data' => 82,
                           'test_data1' => 99,
                           'test_data2' => 'My_String'
                          },
            'string_2' => {
                           'test_data3' => 97,
                           'test_data4' => 67
                          }
           }];

for my $key (keys %{$yaml->[0]}){
    if (my @matches = grep $yaml->[0]{$key}{$_} =~ /My_String/,
                      keys %{ $yaml->[0]->{$key} }
       ){
        print "$key: @matches\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is a hash of hashes, then you need to explicitly traverse your data:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use YAML;

my $hashref = Load(<<'END_YAML');
---
string_1:
  test_data: 82
  test_data1: 99
  test_data2: My_string
string_2:
  test_data3: 97
  test_data4: 67
END_YAML

SEARCH:
while (my ($k1, $v1) = each %$hashref) {
    while (my ($k2, $v2) = each %$v1) {
        if ($v2 =~ /My_string/) {
            print "$k1 -> $k2 -> $v2\n";
            last SEARCH;
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
string_1 -> test_data2 -> My_string
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you Miller.